# Addin word : Load header and footer from base64 file

Tags: office-addins, word-addins

I have a .docx encoded in base64 and I try to put this document in a blank Word with my Word Adding tool.
(WordApi 1.3 / Angular 7)

I already tried to use `context.document.body.insertFileFromBase64(this.myFileBase64, Word.InsertLocation.replace);` but it doesn't include my header nor footer (of course, it's only loading the body).

Then I tried to get this header from another document using
`context.document.sections.getFirst().getHeader("Primary");`
but it doesn't work neither

The only way I find was to load my base64 file in a new Word instance, but it's closing my addin and erasing my settings

```
  let docWord:Word.DocumentCreated;
  docWord = app.createDocument(this.myFileBase64);
  docWord.open();
```

Can I load the entire Word file (header body footer) in a Word document ?

Is there a way to load/reload my base64 file into a Word instance ?

Cross posted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/359062/addin-word-load-header-and-footer-from-base64-file.html).

Thanks.